# Consulta con Inner join me muestra los resultados dos veces con 3 tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Camaradas a ver si me ayudan,
Datos:
El po 1011 tiene solo dos lineas, una por 44 lbs y la otra por 2200
de la linea 44 sea han recibido todas, osea el balance es 0 y la line de 220 se han recibido 1000. La pregunta es; porque me aparece dos veces los recibos.

```
select   receive_number as 'Rec#', 
po_number as 'PO#', ri.receive_date as 'Date', item_code as 'Part#', 
item_descripcion as 'Part Desc', pod.quantity as 'Order Qty', ri.quantity as 'Qty Rec', 
balance as 'Bal', receive_via as 'Rec Via', tracking as 'Tracking', lote as Lote, 
  pod.price, receive_from, 
receive_via, ri.location_id
from receive_info as ri 
inner join purchase_order_details as pod on pod.order_id = ri.order_id 
inner join purchase_order as po on po.id=pod.order_id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Deberás revisar las tablas que intervienen; así con el resultado y el SQL no (me) da para más que sugerirte checar las tablas; por ejemplo con `ri` tienes un campo `status` puede algo te falte algo similar y otra columna aplicarla en alguna de las otras tablas.

Comment: si pudieras añadirnos un ejemplo utilizando http://sqlfiddle.com/ sería genial ya que podríamos ver la estructura y los datos etc..

Comment: El problema está en la lógica de la consulta, si revisas bien, no te está devolviendo 2 veces los resultados, son filas con valores diferentes.

Comment: ¿Qué necesitas? ¿Un renglón por línea o un renglón por recibo?